# Using output from CASE in a new CASE (SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

Can someone tell me how to use the output of a `CASE` statement as input in the next `CASE` statement in t-SQL?

**exampleTable**

```
id | itemNo | samplesLeft
-------------------------
 1 |   001  |       104
 2 |   003  |        53
 3 |   002  |       193
 4 |   001  |        32
```

I would like a query which returns all of this, as well as a boolean telling whether or not it was a factory born error. An error is considered factory born, if less than ten samples has been used. My idea was to first use `CASE` to make a column, showing how many samples has been used, like such:

**Query**

```
SELECT
id,
itemNo,
samplesLeft,
CASE 
     WHEN itemNo= 001 
         THEN 200 - samplesLeft

         WHEN itemNo= 002
         THEN 300 - samplesLeft

         WHEN itemNo= 003
         THEN 400 - samplesLeft                     

     ELSE 100 - samplesLeft
END AS samplesUsed

FROM exampleTable
```

Then I would like to use the samplesUsed as input in another `CASE`, to make a boolean called `factoryError`. Stating TRUE if `samplesUsed < 10`. How to do this?

Comment: Add full query and some db table record sample to get more appropriate answer

Comment: I will try to fix something. Unfortunately I am not at liberty to share the actual database conent, and I have to anonymize the query a bit as well.

Comment: sure anonymize as much as you can, but share atleast the mockup

Comment: I tried to make a more complete example, and I clarified the question.

Comment: You can copy the text from CASE through to the matching END and paste it anywhere you want the value, but normally it's preferable to do nested selects `SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT ...) AS a`. That way you can give the inner CASE result a column name and use that in the outer SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a sub query like,

```
select 
    x.*,
    case 
        when samplesUsed < 10 then 'Error'
        else 'right'
    end as status
from (  
    select 
        t.*,
        CASE 
            WHEN itemNo = 001 THEN 200 - samplesLeft
            WHEN itemNo = 002 THEN 300 - samplesLeft
            WHEN itemNo = 003 THEN 400 - samplesLeft
            ELSE 100 - samplesLeft
        END AS samplesUsed
    from tbl
) x
```

Comment: It worked, and I learned how sub-queries works as well. Thanks :-).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad way to do it, but if you have a column with info of starting number of samples you can fix query and make it better .... but here is one way to get exactly what you wanted

```
create table #TempTableSam (itemNo nvarchar(5), samplesLeft int)
insert into #TempTableSam (itemNo, samplesLeft)
values ('001',50),('002',10),('003',20), ('004',80)

select itemNo, samplesLeft,
case
   WHEN itemNo = '001' and 200 - samplesLeft < 190 then 'More than 10 samples has been used'
   WHEN itemNo = '002' and 300 - samplesLeft < 280 then 'More than 10 samples has been used'
   WHEN itemNo = '003' and 200 - samplesLeft < 190 then 'More than 10 samples has been used'
   WHEN itemNo = '004' and 200 - samplesLeft < 190 then 'More than 10 samples has been used'
  else 'Less then 10 samples has been used'
END as UsedSamples
from #TempTableSam
```

Output would be something like this

```
itemNo  samplesLeft          UsedSamples
 001        50       More than 10 samples has been used
 002        10       Less then 10 samples has been used
 003        20       More than 10 samples has been used
 004        80       More than 10 samples has been used
```

Comment: Bad way or not, thank for you input. I am gonna read up a bit on temporary tables. It seems interesting

Answer (score 1):

You could put your working query as CTE and continue below...

```
WITH YourSELECTasCTE AS
(
    SELECT
    id,
    itemNo,
    samplesLeft,
    CASE 
         WHEN itemNo= 001 
             THEN 200 - samplesLeft

             WHEN itemNo= 002
             THEN 300 - samplesLeft

             WHEN itemNo= 003
             THEN 400 - samplesLeft                     

         ELSE 100 - samplesLeft
    END AS samplesUsed

    FROM exampleTable
)
SELECT * --do whatever you want here
FROM YourSELECTasCTE
```

Comment: I actually considered using `WITH x AS...`, I just couldn't remember the syntax. Thanks for reminding me :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
SELECT  id ,
        itemNo ,
        samplesLeft ,
        CASE WHEN ( CASE WHEN itemNo = '001' THEN 200 - samplesLeft
                         WHEN itemNo = '002' THEN 300 - samplesLeft
                         WHEN itemNo = '003' THEN 400 - samplesLeft
                         ELSE 100 - samplesLeft
                    END ) < 10 THEN 'factory born error'
             ELSE 'ok'
        END AS samplesUsed
FROM    exampleTable
```

test:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked just as intended, along with some of the other solution.